# "one hour earlier"

Tags: prepositions

> *I would like to ask you whether it is possible to postpone our meeting **one hour earlier**.*

Does a native speaker find the part "one hour earlier" OK? I want to suggest that the meeting could start not at 17.00 but at 16.00. Not sure whether there should not be some preposition before "one hour".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sentence structure is fine, but it makes no sense to use "earlier" with "postpone":

> **[postpone](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/postpone)** (v): Cause or arrange for (something) to take place at a time **later** than that first scheduled.

If you want to make an appointment earlier than originally scheduled, use "reschedule" or a variations such as "move", "move up" or "move earlier".

> Is it possible to **move** our appointment (to) **one hour earlier**?